# open sets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: borel-sets

I would like to define a $\mathbb{N}$-valued random variable to define the $\sigma$-algebra generated by this random variable. In my course, we've define only $\sigma$-algebras on borelians of $\mathbb{R}$ ( by the set $\{ X^{-1}(A), A \in B(\mathbb{R}) \}$ for the real case). So what would be borelian of $\mathbb{N}$? Is that just disjoint elements of $\mathbb{N}$ ? Thanks

Comment: All $1$-element subsets of $\mathbb N$ are Borel sets, but so are all the (at most) countable unions of those, implying that *every* subset of $\mathbb N$ is a Borel set.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Heck, every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is **open**, at least with the usual topology.